# What is the difference between multiply and dot functions that is used to merge layer in Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, convolution, convolutional-neural-network

I want to merge two CNN deep learning model using Keras and would like to know what is the difference multiply and dot functions that is used to merge layer?

```
keras.layers.multiply(inputs)


keras.layers.dot(inputs, axes, normalize=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `multiply()` function performs element-wise multiplication. For example, let us consider 1D CNN for simplicity and you pass two inputs of batch size `b` with a tensor length of 5, the output will be (b,5) as it's element-wise multiplication.
Let us assume two tensors of length 5 as follows: `[1,2,3,4,5]` and `[6,7,8,9,10]`, the result shall be `[6,14,24,36,50]` as it's just element-wise multiplication.

In the case of `dot()`, it takes the dot product, and the dot product for 1D is mathematically defined as: `a.b = sum(a_i * b_i)`, where `i` ranges from 0 to n-1; where n is the number of elements in vector a and b. (For 2-D , you can consider it as matrix multiplication). So the result shall be of length `(b,1)` where `b` is the  batch size. In case of out example, the results of dot product of `[1,2,3,4,5]` and `[6,7,8,9,10]` shall be `[130]`